How do find specific string in file?
I have a file that show bridges with IP and port numbers. I didn't find any question to solve my problem. Those numbers are changing frequently, I always want to put in variable only numbers   after  :     string.
The following command doesn't work
grep -rnw file -e ':*'
file:
Bridge obfs4 54.xx.xx.xx:1426 ....
Bridge obfs4 212.xxx.xx.xxx:8080 ...
Bridge obfs4 82.xx.xxx.xx:12447 ...
Bridge obfs4 46.xx.xxx.xxx:65231 ...

In above file I would like to print the folllow numbers
1426
8080
12447
65231

How can I do that?
The right command , grep ,find awk.....
UPDATE:
Thank you all people to help me. I am sorry but not example below can works. I am very sorry to forgot to say that file has multiple numbers and :
I tried all examples. The only example that works with problems is
grep -Po '(?<=:)[0-9]+' file

Above example show multiple numbers after :
My lines are at the end of the file. I think it is complicated
Thank you
SECOND UPDATE
I upload all file
 Configuration file for a typical Tor user
## Last updated 9 October 2013 for Tor 0.2.5.2-alpha.
## (may or may not work for much older or much newer versions of Tor.)
##
## Lines that begin with "## " try to explain what's going on. Lines
## that begin with just "#" are disabled commands: you can enable them
## by removing the "#" symbol.
##
## See 'man tor', or https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html,
## for more options you can use in this file.
##
## Tor will look for this file in various places based on your platform:
## https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq#torrc

## Tor opens a socks proxy on port 9050 by default -- even if you don't
## configure one below. Set "SocksPort 0" if you plan to run Tor only
## as a relay, and not make any local application connections yourself.
#SocksPort 9050 # Default: Bind to localhost:9050 for local connections.
#SocksPort 192.168.0.1:9100 # Bind to this address:port too.

## Entry policies to allow/deny SOCKS requests based on IP address.
## First entry that matches wins. If no SocksPolicy is set, we accept
## all (and only) requests that reach a SocksPort. Untrusted users who
## can access your SocksPort may be able to learn about the connections
## you make.
#SocksPolicy accept 192.168.0.0/16
#SocksPolicy reject *

## Logs go to stdout at level "notice" unless redirected by something
## else, like one of the below lines. You can have as many Log lines as
## you want.
##
## We advise using "notice" in most cases, since anything more verbose
## may provide sensitive information to an attacker who obtains the logs.
##
## Send all messages of level 'notice' or higher to /var/log/tor/notices.log
#Log notice file /var/log/tor/notices.log
## Send every possible message to /var/log/tor/debug.log
#Log debug file /var/log/tor/debug.log
## Use the system log instead of Tor's logfiles
#Log notice syslog
## To send all messages to stderr:
#Log debug stderr

## Uncomment this to start the process in the background... or use
## --runasdaemon 1 on the command line. This is ignored on Windows;
## see the FAQ entry if you want Tor to run as an NT service.
#RunAsDaemon 1

## The directory for keeping all the keys/etc. By default, we store
## things in $HOME/.tor on Unix, and in Application Data\tor on Windows.
#DataDirectory /var/lib/tor

## The port on which Tor will listen for local connections from Tor
## controller applications, as documented in control-spec.txt.
#ControlPort 9051
## If you enable the controlport, be sure to enable one of these
## authentication methods, to prevent attackers from accessing it.
#HashedControlPassword 16:872860B76453A77D60CA2BB8C1A7042072093276A3D701AD684053EC4C
#CookieAuthentication 1

############### This section is just for location-hidden services ###

## Once you have configured a hidden service, you can look at the
## contents of the file ".../hidden_service/hostname" for the address
## to tell people.
##
## HiddenServicePort x y:z says to redirect requests on port x to the
## address y:z.

#HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
#HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80

#HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/other_hidden_service/
#HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
#HiddenServicePort 22 127.0.0.1:22

################ This section is just for relays #####################
#
## See https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-relay for details.

## Required: what port to advertise for incoming Tor connections.
#ORPort 9001
## If you want to listen on a port other than the one advertised in
## ORPort (e.g. to advertise 443 but bind to 9090), you can do it as
## follows.  You'll need to do ipchains or other port forwarding
## yourself to make this work.
#ORPort 443 NoListen
#ORPort 127.0.0.1:9090 NoAdvertise

## The IP address or full DNS name for incoming connections to your
## relay. Leave commented out and Tor will guess.
#Address noname.example.com

## If you have multiple network interfaces, you can specify one for
## outgoing traffic to use.
# OutboundBindAddress 10.0.0.5

## A handle for your relay, so people don't have to refer to it by key.
#Nickname ididnteditheconfig

## Define these to limit how much relayed traffic you will allow. Your
## own traffic is still unthrottled. Note that RelayBandwidthRate must
## be at least 20 KB.
## Note that units for these config options are bytes per second, not bits
## per second, and that prefixes are binary prefixes, i.e. 2^10, 2^20, etc.
#RelayBandwidthRate 100 KB  # Throttle traffic to 100KB/s (800Kbps)
#RelayBandwidthBurst 200 KB # But allow bursts up to 200KB/s (1600Kbps)

## Use these to restrict the maximum traffic per day, week, or month.
## Note that this threshold applies separately to sent and received bytes,
## not to their sum: setting "4 GB" may allow up to 8 GB total before
## hibernating.
##
## Set a maximum of 4 gigabytes each way per period.
#AccountingMax 4 GB
## Each period starts daily at midnight (AccountingMax is per day)
#AccountingStart day 00:00
## Each period starts on the 3rd of the month at 15:00 (AccountingMax
## is per month)
#AccountingStart month 3 15:00

## Administrative contact information for this relay or bridge. This line
## can be used to contact you if your relay or bridge is misconfigured or
## something else goes wrong. Note that we archive and publish all
## descriptors containing these lines and that Google indexes them, so
## spammers might also collect them. You may want to obscure the fact that
## it's an email address and/or generate a new address for this purpose.
#ContactInfo Random Person <nobody AT example dot com>
## You might also include your PGP or GPG fingerprint if you have one:
#ContactInfo 0xFFFFFFFF Random Person <nobody AT example dot com>

## Uncomment this to mirror directory information for others. Please do
## if you have enough bandwidth.
#DirPort 9030 # what port to advertise for directory connections
## If you want to listen on a port other than the one advertised in
## DirPort (e.g. to advertise 80 but bind to 9091), you can do it as
## follows.  below too. You'll need to do ipchains or other port
## forwarding yourself to make this work.
#DirPort 80 NoListen
#DirPort 127.0.0.1:9091 NoAdvertise
## Uncomment to return an arbitrary blob of html on your DirPort. Now you
## can explain what Tor is if anybody wonders why your IP address is
## contacting them. See contrib/tor-exit-notice.html in Tor's source
## distribution for a sample.
#DirPortFrontPage /etc/tor/tor-exit-notice.html

## Uncomment this if you run more than one Tor relay, and add the identity
## key fingerprint of each Tor relay you control, even if they're on
## different networks. You declare it here so Tor clients can avoid
## using more than one of your relays in a single circuit. See
## https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq#MultipleRelays
## However, you should never include a bridge's fingerprint here, as it would
## break its concealability and potentionally reveal its IP/TCP address.
#MyFamily $keyid,$keyid,...

## A comma-separated list of exit policies. They're considered first
## to last, and the first match wins. If you want to _replace_
## the default exit policy, end this with either a reject *:* or an
## accept *:*. Otherwise, you're _augmenting_ (prepending to) the
## default exit policy. Leave commented to just use the default, which is
## described in the man page or at
## https://www.torproject.org/documentation.html
##
## Look at https://www.torproject.org/faq-abuse.html#TypicalAbuses
## for issues you might encounter if you use the default exit policy.
##
## If certain IPs and ports are blocked externally, e.g. by your firewall,
## you should update your exit policy to reflect this -- otherwise Tor
## users will be told that those destinations are down.
##
## For security, by default Tor rejects connections to private (local)
## networks, including to your public IP address. See the man page entry
## for ExitPolicyRejectPrivate if you want to allow "exit enclaving".
##
#ExitPolicy accept *:6660-6667,reject *:* # allow irc ports but no more
#ExitPolicy accept *:119 # accept nntp as well as default exit policy
#ExitPolicy reject *:* # no exits allowed

## Bridge relays (or "bridges") are Tor relays that aren't listed in the
## main directory. Since there is no complete public list of them, even an
## ISP that filters connections to all the known Tor relays probably
## won't be able to block all the bridges. Also, websites won't treat you
## differently because they won't know you're running Tor. If you can
## be a real relay, please do; but if not, be a bridge!
#BridgeRelay 1
## By default, Tor will advertise your bridge to users through various
## mechanisms like https://bridges.torproject.org/. If you want to run
## a private bridge, for example because you'll give out your bridge
## address manually to your friends, uncomment this line:
#PublishServerDescriptor 0


UseBridges 1
ClientTransportPlugin obfs4 exec /usr/bin/obfs4proxy

Bridge obfs4 34.35.150.52:1426 051NhqJIxbDg iat-mode=0
Bridge obfs4 222.223.61.139:8080 DA96CA0221FC90A47E228ui0SQYQEA iat-mode=0
Bridge obfs4 212.24.293.33:12447 294AF2AD+aw iat-mode=0
Bridge obfs4 44.138.220.132:66831 85DDB88F43F5ZZZCthOw iat-mode=0

VirtualAddrNetworkIPv4 10.192.0.0/10
AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
TransPort 9040 IsolateClientAddr IsolateClientProtocol IsolateDestAddr IsolateDestPort
DNSPort 5353


Try awk '/:/ {gsub(/^[^:]*:/,""); print $1}' file

@Wiimm It doesn't work. Above command shows many things.

I created an input file with your example and it works. I guess it works not for you, because you input files is different from you example.

I am very sorry to forgot to say that file has multiple numbers and : we will not to able to help unless you show the entire file

@Wiimm I am sorry I upload entire file. The file has multiple : I forgot to say. I am very sorry. My lines are at the end of file

$ awk -v FS='[: ]' '/^Bridge/ {print $4}' file
1426
8080
12447
65231


Or -F '[: ]' instead of -v FS='[: ]', just saves a couple of chars typing.

I saw someone saying here on SO that using -F is a bad taste and even that open source project maintainers would not accept it. It's a matter of taste, of course.

Whoever said that is wrong. -F is commonplace, has been around as long as awk has and is (and will continue to be) supported by all awks. Personally I wish awk had been designed such that -F x was equivalent to -v FS=x -v OFS=x instead of just -v FS=x but that ship sailed a very long time ago! Actually... I wish todays FS was named IFS and when you set FS it overrides IFS and OFS but again, not going to happen. It's weird to me that the same group of people who invented shell and awk came up with IFS for shell but FS for awk. Ah well...

@ArkadiuszDrabczyk It doesn't work. Above command shows many things.

@user21379959: post the entire file without ... part and the output you get.

@ArkadiuszDrabczyk I did

@user21379959: does it work now?

@ArkadiuszDrabczyk You are the God. Thank you my friend!

awk is too complicated, I suggest this simple solution (but a bit less efficient) :
cat <FILE> | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | cut -d ':' -f 2
Explanation :

The first cut splits by space, and takes the 3rd string, which is the IP:PORT
The second cut splits by colon (':') and takes the second string, which is the PORT


@Cristophe Cristopge Thank but  It doesn't work. Above command shows many things.

Another way using sed:
sed -e 's/.*:\([0-9]*\)\ .*/\1/' test

Replaced the line with all [0-9] between the : and the space ( ) afterwards.
Output:
1426
8080
12447
65231


any reason why the space was being escaped ?

If there's only one :[0-9] pattern per line, you may want to try grep -P:
$ grep -Po '(?<=:)[0-9]+' file
1426
8080
12447
65231


Nice! Possible simplification: \d could be used instead of [0-9]

If I understood your question correctly, you are not looking for a specific string and/or pattern, but you are trying to extract a specific field.
You could use the cut command to solve your problem in two steps.
First, split each line on white space (-d ' ') and extract the third field (-f 3), with the IP address and the port number:
cut -d ' ' -f 3

The output would be:
54.xx.xx.xx:1426
212.xxx.xx.xxx:8080
82.xx.xxx.xx:12447
46.xx.xxx.xxx:65231

Then, you could use cut again to get the second field (-f 2) after splittling on colons (-d ':'):
cut -d ':' -f 2

Finally, combine the two cut commands using a shell pipeline:
cut -d ' ' -f 3 file | cut -d ':' -f 2

